# Android Studio - Updating the Version of com.google.android.gms to 11.6.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I always get this error in my android studio, and i dont have any idea about this, i've tried to find the solution on the Internet but i still cant find it.

This is my Gradle Image :

[image]

this is the Error Image :

[image]

Comment: read error log. use 11.6.0

Comment: Do you have to use **ALL** the Google play services? Which ones are you actually using?

Comment: Pro tip: please add configuration files to questions as text, not images. Images are not compatible with screen-readers, clipboards and search engines, and so are not the most helpful format for people who could help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your project the errors comes like you have not add **project level** google **classpath** and not apply **google plugin** in **app level** gradle so,

**Add in project level gradle**

```
  classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
```

**Add in APP level gradle and google plugin**

```
  dependencies {

      compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
      compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'

   }
     //  ADD THIS AT THE BOTTOM
     apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**NOTE-:** If you want to add more Google gradle for your requirements then add with **same version**.

**For More** https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Google Services your Gradles should look something like this:

App level build.gradle should look like

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.firebase.firebase-crash'
android {

    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxxxxx"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 11
        versionName "1.10"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
        }
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.config
            resValue("string", "PORT_NUMBER", "8081")
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    debugCompile project(':debug-db')
    compile project(':tracker')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.6.0'
   /* compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.6.0'*/
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.6.0'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

As you could see, no use for build, but it completely depends on your use `/* compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.4.0'*/`

And root level gradle.build is:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        classpath 'com.google.firebase:firebase-plugins:1.1.1'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Make sure your Gradle distribution in `gradle-wrapper.properties` is

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.3-all.zip
```